# ng-change not working with ng option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my angular code and i need to receive object by `changeFilterOption(filter)` function, this objects are looping in ng-option. But it does not work;return `undefines`.

```
<select ng-change="changeFilterOption(filter)" class="js-example-basic-single form-control" ng-model="attribute[' + countInc + '].name" ng-options="filter.name as filter.uiName for filter in filters"></select>

$scope.changeFilterOption=function(filter){
  console.log(filter);//undefined
};
```

Comment: Can you make js fiddle for it syntax seems to be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass the selected value to the `changeFilterOption` function, Then this is not the way you need to follow, Try like this,

```
<select ng-change="changeFilterOption(attribute[' + countInc + '].name)" ng-model="attribute[' + countInc + '].name" ng-options="filter.name as filter.uiName for filter in filters">
```

here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/pyP6NQ48TlQcP2fJW7Dp?p=preview)

then the value of the `select` will be passed to the `changeFilterOption(filter)` in `filter` parameter.

And if you looking to pass the `filter` object to the `changeFilterOption(filter)` then you need to modify the `select` as below,

```
<select ng-change="changeFilterOption(attribute[' + countInc + '].name)" ng-model="attribute[' + countInc + '].name" ng-options="filter as filter.uiName for filter in filters">
```

this will select the `filter` as the `select` value, and display the `filter.uiName` as option text.

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gb7JCOQuMuJwdHMT7R2b?p=preview)

Comment: This works but I can't find any documentation for `attribute[' + countInc + '].name`. What makes this work?

Answer (score 1):

in your `*.js` file you can simply `watch` for the changes :-

```
$scope.$watch('your-model-name', function (newValue, oldValue){ 
    //newVal is the changed value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        <select ng-change="changeFilterOption(filter)" class="js-example-basic-single form-control" ng-model="attribute[' + countInc + '].name" ng-options="filter as filter.uiName for filter in filters"></select>

          $scope.changeFilterOption=function(filter){
                     console.log(filter);//undefined
            };
```